# Resource$NotFoundException for layout when a using tinymce

Tags: android, tinymce, assets

i am using `tinymce` editor inside my app in a webview. in my assets folder i have three fonts and `tinymce.html` and a folder contains `tinymce` files like this:
[image: assets View]

problem is my app isn't runing on device cause the `resource$notFoundException` in `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);` and the icon and app_name gone in launcher list. but when i remove `tinymce` folder from assets, it works fine without problem.

i need this folder in `assets` . how can i deal with this problem?

Comment: why do you need it in assets?

Comment: where else i can put it? in an activity i will open a webview and load `tinymce.html`